# BigQuery Return Single Record Value(s) from Joined Table

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to return a field from the most recent record in a joined (related) table. I might have done this with a nested select statement but that is not supported in BigQuery.

```
Table 1: tblIncidents
- incidentId
- incidentName
- clientName
- incidentDescription
- incidentDate
```

```
Table 2: tblActivity
- activityId
- incidentId
- activityDate
- activityStatus
```

There could be between 0 and n records in tblActivity for a given incident.

I'll be displaying several incidents based on the `incidentDate`.

Also, if there are no activity records, the field can be null or perhaps I could set a string value of "no activity".

I know this doesn't work but something like this would in MS SQL Server. I'm unsure of the best way to do this in BigQuery.

```
Select I.incidentId, I.incidentDate, I.clientName, I.incidentName, 
(Select A.activityStatus FROM tblActivity A 
Where A.incidentId = I.incidentId as activityStatus ORDER BY A.activityDate DESC limit 1) as activityStatus,
incidentDescription 
FROM tblIncidents I WHERE clientName = 'a given client name'
```

Thank you in advance for any insight into which direction to go with this.

Comment: Have you tried making a CTE prior to the main query?

Comment: Why do you believe the correlated sub-query doesn't work in BigQuery?  Are you getting error messages? If so, please include the error in your question.  *(I can see at least one syntax error. Remove the `AS activityStatus` from the Middle of line 3, in the `WHERE` clause.)*

Comment: Alternatively, an analytic function using LAST_VALUE after ordering would do the job

Comment: @paul Only if you also use DISTINCT, as analytic functions aren't Aggregates (and so multiple rows will still return).

Comment: @MatBailie Quite right.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Sorry I didn't get back to this. Was pulled onto another project briefly.

I'm working on this today. I did get an error message - can't recall but hopefully I'll either have it working or have the error message in a bit.

I also had to spend some time getting familiar with CTE's and how they will help in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach, which avoids `DISTINCT` on top of the analytical query results:

```
with activityMax as (
    select * from (
       select 
          incidentId, 
          activityId, 
          activityStatus,
          row_number() over (partition by incidentId order by activityDate desc) as activity_rnk 
       from tblActivity
    ) where activity_rnk = 1
)

select 
   I.incidentId, 
   I.incidentDate, 
   I.clientName, 
   I.incidentName, 
   A.activityId, 
   coalesce(A.activityStatus, "NO ACTIVITY") as activityStatus
from tblIncidents I
left join activityMax A on I.incidentId = A.incidentId
```

Comment: I used this answer - modified for a few additional fields. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches but my first would be to use the analytic function `LAST_VALUE()` with the appropriate window:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tblIncidents.incidentId
    ,tblIncidents.incidentDate
    ,tblIncidents.clientName
    ,tblIncidents.incidentName

    # partition by incidentID, order by date asc, grab the last value
    # (equivalently, order by date desc, grab the first value)
    ,LAST_VALUE(tblActivity.activityStatus) OVER(partition by tblActivity.incidentId ORDER BY activityDate ASC) as latestActivityStatus
    ,incidentDescription 
FROM tblIncidents
JOIN tblActivity USING(incidentId)
WHERE clientName = 'client1'
```

As emphasised by MatBailie in the comments, a `DISTINCT` is also needed to avoid the JOIN returning duplicates.

If you don't like the DISTINCT, you can use a subquery like you first mentioned and filter it using a WHERE clause. I didn't use a JOIN for this one.

```
Select 
    tblIncidents.incidentId
    ,tblIncidents.incidentDate
    ,tblIncidents.clientName
    ,tblIncidents.incidentName

    # subquery        
    ,(SELECT tblActivity.activityStatus FROM tblActivity 
        WHERE tblActivity.incidentId = tblIncidents.incidentId
        ORDER BY activityDate DESC 
        LIMIT 1
     ) as latestActivityStatus

    ,tblIncidents.incidentDescription 
FROM tblIncidents
WHERE clientName = 'client1'
```

In both cases, I have defined CTEs earlier in my query (not shown here), called "tblIncidents" and "tblActivity" using `WITH`.

Do either of these approaches help you?

Comment: In the correlated sub-query, the correlation should be on incidentId, and both references should be fully qualified (as it should be in the PARTITION clause of the first query too...)

Comment: Yep, thanks; now corrected. I was more trying to give an example of the approach than a "full answer" but, in hindsight, I should have either indicated that or done it properly from the start.